# Добавить шаблоны Activity в Eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, eclipse, activity

При создании android проекта в Eclipse на этапе выбора `Activity` нет всех шаблонов `Activity`, которые мне нужны (в частности, сейчас мне нужна `Basic Activity`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно в Eclipse добавить другие шаблоны активностей?

Comment: самый простой(и скорее всего правильный) способ - переход на android studio

Comment: Это да, но хочется разобраться все-таки как это сделать в Eclipse :) В крайнем случае придется переходить на Android Studio, но Eclipse больше по душе лично мне

Comment: ровно по такой же причине сам не хотел переходить на AS, но душа оказывается быстро привыкает к хорошему :)

Comment: google отказалась от Eclipse, как среды разработки Android, более года назад, поэтому подобные проблемы будут появлятся регулярно и разумно было бы перейти на Android Studio. Где взять нужный вам шаблон ответить затруднительно, кроме как сделать его самому. Как сделать шаблон в Eclipse множество гайдов в интернете.

Comment: душа душой, а функциональность инструмента все таки должна быть более значима

Comment: Когда вы в достаточной степени освоите все возможности Android Studio, душа к Eclipse у вас лежать уже вряд ли будет. После ~2 лет на AS довелось поработать с Eclipse и это было болью, AS на порядок более мощный инструмент, хотя переход в свое время сопровождался ломками.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо. Буду переходить на AS :)